# Как задать путь в Ubuntu для сохранения файлов в Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, vps, fileupload

В моем приложении на Spring MVC есть необходимость загружать файлы пользователей. Приложение запускается на Tomcat. На локальной машине я указываю путь к папке для сохранения файлов так **imagesUrl=c:/images/** (в файле my.properties) и в контроллере получаю это свойство как путь. Все работает.

Далее я запускаю приложение на сервере (Ubuntu 14.04), и в файле настроек меняю значение на **imagesUrl=/images/**. Предварительно создал папку `/images` и прописал ей `chmod ugo+rw`. В catalina.out ошибки только при попытке достать файлы из каталога. В чем может быть проблема?

РЕДАКТИРОВАНО:
так сохраняю:

```
public String save(List<Image> images) {
        if (images.size() == 0) return null;

        String imagesUrl = generalProperties.getProperty("imagesUrl");

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        for ( int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++ ) {
            Image image = images.get(i);
            String location = imagesUrl + image.getUser() + "/" + image.getTitle();
            File pathFile = new File(location);
            if (!pathFile.exists()) {
                pathFile.mkdir();
            }

            pathFile = new File(location + "/" + image.getName());

            try {
                image.getFile().transferTo(pathFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            session.save(image);
            if ( i % 20 == 0 ) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return "Advert saved successfully";
    }
```

так получаю:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imageDisplay", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void showImage(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
                      @RequestParam("advertId") Integer advertId,
                      @RequestParam("user") String user,
                      @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    String imagesUrl = generalProperties.getProperty("imagesUrl");

        File file = new File(imagesUrl + user + "/" + advertService.getAdvertById(advertId).getTitle() + "/" + fileName);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Comment: Добавьте саму ошибку, стектрейс

Comment: где это посмотреть?

Comment: который в catalina.out, что за Exception?

Comment: Ну и сам код, как сохраняете и читаете картинки

Comment: я очистил папку logs и catalina.out не пересоздается((

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил код работы с файлами

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50621/discussion-between-mrfylypenko-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 1):

Пример на *`Pure Java`* с использованием [`@WebServlet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html).

```java
@WebServlet(name = "test", urlPatterns = "/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Получаем разделитель файлов операционной системы
        // windows - '\' UNIX - '/'
        String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        // В моем случае tomcat установлен в каталоге
        // /opt/apache-tomcat


        // Получаем изображение
        // Путь начинается от каталога /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/{your-app-name}/WEB-INF/classes
        InputStream is = test.class.getResourceAsStream(fs + "noimage.png");

        // Записываем изображение
        // Путь начинается от каталога /opt/apache-tomcat/bin/
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(".." + fs + "images" + fs + "filename.png");

        // Записываем файл
        int read;
        while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(read);
        }

        response.getWriter().println("done");
    }
}
```